# Class-validator: remove a property on validation, based on the value of another property

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

Using `class-validator` with NestJS, I have this working:

```
export class MatchDeclineReason {
  @IsString()
  @IsEnum(MatchDeclineReasonType)
  @ApiProperty()
  type: MatchDeclineReasonType;

  @ValidateIf(reason => reason.type === MatchDeclineReasonType.Other)
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  freeText: string;
}
```

so that if the `delinceReason.type === Other`, I expect to get a `freeText` string value.

---

However, if the `declineReason.type` is any different from `Other`, I want the `freeText` property to be stripped away.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behaviour without writing a `CustomValidator`?

My `ValidationPipe` configuration:

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      disableErrorMessages: false,
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be achieved by using a custom logic for value transformation:

```
  @ValidateIf(reason => reason.type === MatchDeclineReasonType.Other)
  @Transform((params) =>
    (params.obj.type === MatchDeclineReasonType.Other ? params.value : undefined)
  )
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  freeText: string;
```